# xterm doesn't run shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xterm

so I'm trying to use this command:

```
export DISPLAY=:1; /usr/bin/xterm -hold -e /path/to/shscript
```

Where `shscript` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Restarting ...     $(date)" >> /var/log/mw2.txt
if screen -ls | grep -q 'test'; then
    screen -X -S test quit
    sleep 1000
    screen -d -m -S test wine iw4m.exe -dedicated -console +dw_licensefile license.dat +set net_port "28960" +set party_maxplayers 18 +exec server.cfg +map_rotate +set fs_game "mods/tsd"
else
    screen -d -m -S test wine iw4m.exe -dedicated -console +dw_licensefile license.dat +set net_port "28960" +set party_maxplayers 18 +exec server.cfg +map_rotate +set fs_game "mods/tsd"
fi
```

So I want to launch a new xterm window and it to run a shell script.
But whatever shell script I try to use, it doesn't run it. It just goes blank. All other commands work, but when I put a shell script in it, it just goes blank and does nothing. I can't find a solution for this, please help, thank you.

I get this with `set -x`:

```
++ date
+ echo 'Restarting ... (date)'
+ grep -q test
+ screen -ls
+ screen -d -m -S test -wine iw4m etc...
```

Comment: Is that script marked executable? Does it have a proper shebang (`#!`) line? What does the script look contain?

Comment: Sorry, here it's formatted better: http://pastebin.com/62b3EFG6

Comment: Editing that into the post would have been better (for formatting purposes). Do you see anything in that log file when you run it? Add `set -x` to the top of the script and see if you see anything extra being output about what is running. Can you get *any* script to run correctly this way? Even just a simple one that only runs `echo Hello`?

Comment: Yes that simple script apparently works... And nothing special with `set -x`

In /var/log/mw2.txt it says the Restarting ...     $(date) part. o_o

Comment: Also, when running the restart.sh in VNC manually, it works...

Comment: You don't see anything output to the xterm window (or your current teminal) when you run that command with `set -x` in the script? You should see every line the script runs output (prefixed with a `+`).

Comment: Yes, I do see those lines. But the script doesn't still run.

Comment: You see *what* lines? You see it running `screen`, `grep` and `if`? Do you see it running your `screen` commands? Do you see it running `sleep`? What do you see exactly? (You can just edit the entire output into the question.)

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: So you see it run the `screen` command in the `else` block? But you don't end up with a `screen` session running? Sounds like the `wine` process is having some issue and not working (either itself or the `iw4m` process). You'll need to see if you can get one (or both) of those to log more information about what is going on.

Comment: yea... But it works if I do it manually in VNC though. How can I get such logs?...

Comment: Is `:1` the correct display? Is it still set when the script runs? How are you running the `xterm` command that is failing? Via cron?

Comment: The point is, it just run the screen command. But it does when I run the script manually via VNC. So what's the problem?

Comment: It does run `screen` you see that in the `set -x` output. Which means that `wine` or `iw4m` is failing somehow. How is this being run when it fails? Via a launcher? Via cron? Via something else? Check the environment when it works and when it fails and see if they differ. Redirect standard output and standard error from `screen` (and `wine`) to a file and see if you see anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get exactly what you have asked for...

From screen's man page:

> ```
>    -d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
>            doesn't  attach  to  it.  This  is  useful  for  system startup
>            scripts.
> ```

On the other hand you use -hold for xterm:

> ```
>    -hold   Turn  on  the  hold  resource, i.e., xterm will not immediately
>            destroy its window when the shell command completes.   It  will
>            wait  until you use the window manager to destroy/kill the win‐
>            dow, or if you use the menu entries that send a  signal,  e.g.,
>            HUP or KILL.
> ```

And that's exactly what you see. xterm starts, executes screen which runs, but you don't see the output as screen does not attach to the virtual terminal. Since screen has detached the shell script exits and xterm holds the window for you to destroy it at your leisure.

I bet that if in another xterm you attach to the session with `screen -S test` you'll see the output.

Comment: @Wlnt That's not quite what was said. The point here was that you don't see anything in the xterm because you started screen detached but that it was *actually* running and were you to attach in some other terminal you would have seen it. Is that what was happening? (You didn't actually look for a running `screen` process you just assumed it didn't work because you didn't see any output?)

Comment: Nevermind. I doesn't work. The script still works when I run it manually. The main point isn't that it's blank, but it doesn't run the game server. I mean it's supposed to run the wine iw4m.exe etc. And it doesn't. So this is still unsolved.

Comment: It* .. ugh hard to type on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. It was the `wine` command failing. I changed some stuff, and it works now. I had to put `cd /home/MW2` in the script for it to be able to run the iw4m.exe, then screen -S etc.